# Can the eigenvalues of a Sturm-Liouville problem have a multiplicity of more than 2?

Tags: orthogonality, singularity, sturm-liouville

I have a Sturm-Liouville problem in the following form:
$$(py')'-qy=-\lambda wy$$
defined in $x \in [0,L]$ and $L<\infty$ with periodic boundary condition.
where in my case, $q=0$ and $p=w$ are piecewise constant functions taking the values either $1$ or a small value $\epsilon \ge 0$ in every subinterval.

When $\epsilon>0$ I can derive valid eigenvalue/eigenfunctions without any problem; i.e. the eigenvalues multiplicity is at most 2 and the eigenfunctions can be orthogonalized e.g. using Gram-Schmidt process (since they are not necessarily orthogonal).

However I had noticed as $\epsilon \to 0$, some of the consecutive eigenvalues converge to a common value and when I choose exactly $\epsilon=0$ (the ideal case), they all combine into one value with a multiplicity of more than 2. whereas I read somewhere that since the differential equation is second order, the multiplicity should be no more than 2. Next I tried to employ the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to orthogonalize the derived eigenfunctions, but it failed to yield an orthogonal set of eigenfunctions and even I checked the solutions had become invalidated.

What is the problem? Is it now singular with $\epsilon=0$? Is it even possible with multiplicity of more than 2? Does orthogonalization have some constraints?

Comment: This is not a Sturm-Liouville problem in its classical form  $\,\, y''+\lambda\,y=0$

Comment: On any interval where $p=0$, you don't even have a differential equation.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I see. But I think the problem is solvable in limit sense. isn't it? Because I already have derived a set of solutions. The only problem is regarding the orthogonalization. please also let me know that the multiplicity number can be greater than 2 or not.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos I think you mention the Liouville's normal form $y''-Qy=-\lambda wy$ which is a transformation of self-adjoint form $(py')'-qy=-\lambda wy$.

Comment: ΟΚ if you can transform it in the standard form then you can solve it!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Please note that the solution is already at hand. that is in fact as you said, the solution is piecewise trigonometric. the problem is that the eigenfunctions can't be orthogonalized.

Comment: When you have p, q, and w equal to 0 on an interval, anything will solve that equation. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Yes you are right. I was just thinking that what I have obtained is a solution for $\epsilon>0$ but for the case of infinitesimally small value. I think there is no solution for the ideal case. However, thank you for having time.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos : The classical form of a Sturm-Liouville equation is obtained through separation of variables, and it looks like this: $Lf=\lambda f$ where $Lf=\frac{1}{w}\left[-(pf')'+qf\right]$. That's what Sturm and Liouville wrote about in their joint work of the early 19th century. This all came out of separation of variables, which was Fourier's technique.

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi : If you have an interior interval where everything is $0$, then you could solve on the other two intervals, and use endpoint conditions to couple the two equations across the void. If that has some meaning, then it is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts that is in fact what I've done.

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi : This is why the problem is not classified as a Sturm -Liouville problem if $p$ is 0 anywhere except the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks professor, your guides were very helpful. According to your last comment, I have decided to set aside the ideal case. For the non-ideal case which can be regarded as a Sturm-Liouville problem, my only challenge is to find the eigenvalues. I have the characteristic equation which is in the form of the determinant of a matrix with trigonometric elements. And I see that the eigenvalues are tightly distributed in the neighborhood of a set of values that I can use as initial guess. The only approach I see is using root finding algorithms. Is there any better suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical Sturm-Liouville problem on a finite interval $[a,b]$ involves the operator
$$
          Lf = \frac{1}{w}\left[-\frac{d}{dx}\left(p\frac{df}{dx}\right)+qf\right]
$$
where $p > 0$ on $(a,b)$ and is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$, where $w$ is positive and piece-wise continuous on $[a,b]$, and where $q$ is piece-wise continuous on $[a,b]$. Conditions can be relaxed on $p,q,w$, but the conditions above are typical for classical cases. If $p$ is strictly positive on $[a,b]$, then the problem is regular. If $p$ vanishes at $a$ and/or $b$, then the operator is considered to be singular. If you want $p$ to be allowed to vanish at an interior point $c\in(a,b)$, then you'll typically need to consider separate problems on $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ and piece the solutions together at $c$.

With this operator $L$, the Sturm-Liouville problem is cast in the setting of weighted space $L^2_w[a,b]$, where the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_w$ is
$$
           \langle f,g\rangle_w = \int_a^b f(x)\overline{g(x)}w(x)dx.
$$
The classical domain of $L$ consists of absolutely continuous functions $f$ on $(a,b)$. Endpoint conditions naturally arise in the context of looking at the symmetry of the operator $L$:
$$
         \langle Lf,g\rangle_w-\langle f,Lg\rangle_w
   =\int_a^b\left\{-(pf')'+qf\right\}\overline{g}-f\left\{-(p\overline{g}')'+q\overline{g}\right\}dx \\
   = \int_a^b -(pf')'\overline{g}+f(p\overline{g}')' dx \\
   = \int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}\left[-(pf')\overline{g}+f(p\overline{g}')\right]dx \\
   = \left.-p\left\{f'\overline{g}-f\overline{g}'\right\}\right|_{x=a}^{b} 
   =  W_p(f,g)|_a^b.
$$
The weighted Wronskian $W_p$ is defined as $W_p(f,g)=p(f\overline{g}'-f'\overline{g})$.

With these common conventions in mind, your situation where $p$ could vanish somewhere on the interior of $[a,b]$ would not be considered as a Sturm-Liouville problem. You would have to break the problem into multiple Sturm-Liouville problems over adjacent intervals.